# I am using Windows 8.1. and I am not able to open Google through Firefox browser

Tags: firefox, windows-8.1, browser

I am using Windows 8.1 and I am using Chrome and Firefox.

Today I tried open www.google.com in FireFox and got an "Untrusted website" error.

The error which I am getting is

```
www.google.co.in uses an invalid security certificate. "(Error code: sec_error_unknown_issuer)".
```

I have not made any changes on my system with respect to 'Family safety settings' or Firewall settings.

I have even re-installed FireFox but still the issue is same.

Can someone help me solve this issue please?

Comment: Try checking your time and date. When the system clocks gets out of sync the invalid certificate error is very common.

Comment: Either you are a victim of [MITM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) or Family Filter is enabled in WIndows. Also refer to [this](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1043310)

Comment: I've had this: are you using Kaspersky? I have found two settings that need to be changed to work round this.

Comment: @JozefLegény `Error code: sec_error_unknown_issuer` is not what you get when the date&time is wrong.